# Oracle Primavera P6 refreshing the screen issue

Tags: primavera

I have installed Oracle Primavera P6 V17 and when I move the divider line between Gantt chart and activities some black lines appeared.

When I refresh the screen or click on the screen these black lines disappear.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: please share screenshots if possible

Answer (score 0):

We all have the same issue. Usually clicking on a new activity is enough to right the screen. No fixes that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Very familiar issue.

a) Upgrade to a newer version or
b) Install more memory or
c) Close memory hungry applications - eg. Teams.